# Простой запрос SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы, связь один-ко-многим. Пусть, таблица т1 - основная.

Соответственно в таблице т2 может [0;N] записей для строки из таблицы т1.
Понятно, что в таблице т2 будет колонка идТ1.

Представим, что у нас в т2 есть колонка статус, допустимые значения: 1 - 5.

Мне нужно выбрать те строки т1, для которых есть строки из т2, причём у всех у них статус не входит в какой-то диапазон, к примеру: 1,2,3.

Я попробовал сделать так:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1Id
WHERE t2.status NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY t2.t1Id
ORDER BY t1.id DESC;
```

Но он отрабатывает некорректно, потому что выбираются даже те строки из т1, где есть хоть одна строка из т2 со статусом 4 или 5.

А какой правильный sql-запрос?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1Id
GROUP BY t2.t1Id
having sum(case when status in(1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end)=0
ORDER BY t1.id DESC;
```

Comment: ругаться на `group by` разве не будет? либо выведет по 1 записи. `oracle` точно бы ругался.

Comment: Oracle ругаться будет, но это же Mysql. ^-)

Comment: А почему группировка по полю t2.t1Id, когда можно (а по логике - и нужно) группировать по t1.id? И - для MySQL можно избавиться от одного преобразования, написав просто _sum(status in(1, 2, 3))=0_.

Comment: Я просто редактировал запрос в вопросе. Но поскольку группировка выполняется после соединения, считаю, что все равно по чем группировать. Но лучше сравнить планы.

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понел у вас задваились данные
должен помочь 
SELECT distinct t1.*